# How to add users to docker container running on a vm

Tags: linux, docker, cloud, docker-machine

I'm running an application inside a container in docker. I would like for my collaborators to be able to log into this vm and administrate the container. I do a `useradd` in the vm but when they login and run `docker ps` they don't see the container, they see: `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host`. Now that I think of it, it makes no sense that they would be able to connect to the docker container I ran, but there should be a way, right?

How do you grant others access to the docker containers you launch, without giving them your login credentials?

Comment: Are the new users added to the docker group? So I think you also need to add your new users to the sudoers file: http://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo . If this helps I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: I solved this by adding them to docker on etc/groups